# Trying to adapt a simple php contact form script

Tags: php, forms, contacts

I am trying to adapt a php script to work with a contact form I am using on my site.
I get the following error when trying to view the page:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file

If I remove the script all together, I can view my page, so I think the script may be incomplete?

The form and script code is as follows:

```
<form name="hongkiat" id="hongkiat-form" method="post" action="index.php">  
            <div id="wrapping" class="clearfix">  
                <section id="aligned">  
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your name" autocomplete="off" tabindex="1" class="txtinput">  
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your e-mail address" autocomplete="off" tabindex="2" class="txtinput">  
                    <input type="url" name="website" id="website" placeholder="Website URL" autocomplete="off" tabindex="3" class="txtinput">  
                    <input type="tel" name="telephone" id="telephone" placeholder="Phone number?(optional)" tabindex="4" class="txtinput">  
                    <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Enter a cool message..." tabindex="5" class="txtblock"></textarea>  
                </section>  
            </div>
            <section id="buttons">  
                <input type="reset" name="reset" id="resetbtn" class="resetbtn" value="Reset">  
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submitbtn" class="submitbtn" tabindex="7" value="Submit this!">  
                <br style="clear:both;">  
            </section>

            <?php
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $website = $_POST['website'];
            $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
            $message = $_POST['message'];
            $from = 'web address here'; 
            $to = 'email here'; 
            $subject = 'Message from mh web';
            $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Website URL: $website\n Telehone: $telephone\n Message:\n $message";
            if ($_POST['submit'])  
            {                
            if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) 
            { 
                echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
            } 
            else 
            { 
                echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
            } 
            ?>

        </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another `}` right before the `?>`, to close the `if($_POST['submit']){` block.  This would be easy to see if the code were properly indented:

```
        if ($_POST['submit'])  
        {                
            if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) 
            { 
                echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
            } 
            else 
            {  
            echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
            }
        // oops!  missing }
        ?>
```